# Is there a standard Facebook Java Api?

Tags: java, spring, facebook

Is there a standard implementation in Java for the Facebook Api?

From what I read the http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/ doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no official Java API.

They had a nice list of all third party java libraries but they deleted that page and prohibited web spiders from accessing it so I can't even get cached version now (wtf is wrong with you facebook?)

[RestFB](http://restfb.com/) is actually pretty much the library to go right now. It supports both old REST api and new OpenGraph stuff. Has lots of examples and actively developed.

That java library you posted was abandoned a year ago. No bugfixes or updates ever since. It works fine with old REST API but doesn't support new one.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that it doesn't work? I'm using `facebook-java-api`, and haven't found any problem yet.

There also exists [RestFB](http://code.google.com/p/restfb/) client, but it not looks like a mature library. And also it haven't maven support :(

Comment: RestFB should be rolling out Maven support this week as part of 1.6.1 (I'm the maintainer).  What do you think needs to be added, or what issues need to be addressed, to make it a mature library?  It's about a year old now.